# On conjugacy of matrices in extension rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, automorphism-group

Let $p$ be any (odd) prime number and consider the group $G=\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}\times\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$. Let $\varphi,\psi$ be automorphisms of $G$ such that the automorphisms induced on $G/pG$ are conjugate. Is it true that $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are conjugate as automorphisms of $G$?

**EDIT**

$\varphi$ and $\psi$ should be $p'$-automorphisms.

Comment: You have surely been here for long enough that you surely know how to ask a good question, rather than just stating the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's incredibly important that you want $p'$-automorphisms. Let $P$ be a finite $p$-group, and let $\Phi(P)$ denote the smallest normal subgroup whose quotient is elementary abelian. (In your case, this is $pG$.) If $\phi$ is a $p'$-automorphism such that $\phi$ induces the identity on $P/\Phi(P)$, then $\phi=1$.

So if one of $\phi$ and $\psi$ were the identity on $G/pG$ then you would be happy. But why don't you assume that $\phi$ and $\psi$ are *equal* on $G/pG$? If they are conjugate then you can do this. Then $\phi\psi^{-1}$ is the identity on $G/pG$, hence is a $p$-automorphism of $G$.

But this is all you can say. If $n\geq 2$ then the group of automorphisms is $Q\rtimes \mathrm{SL}_2(p)$, where $Q$ is some $p$-group. I can easily choose two $p'$-automorphisms lying in two different conjugates of $\mathrm{SL}_2(p)$, with the same action on the quotient, whose product lies in $Q$.

Answer (score 2):

You can take $\varphi$ to be the identity, and say $\psi$ given by the matrix
$$\pmatrix{1&p\\0&1}.$$
As this matrix is the identity modulo $p$, $\psi$ induces the identity on $G/pG$.

Comment: Is there any chance you may have the same with $p'$-automorphisms? (that was actually my goal)

Comment: That looks unlikely; a nonzero element of $\Bbb F_p^*$ lifts uniquely to.a $p'$-root of unity modulo $p^n$, so if your matrix is diagonalisable modulo $p$ surely it can be uniquely lifted. I'm sure the same holds for non-diagonalisable matrices, if you work over a field of order $p^2$. @W4cc0